# CSS Grid Problems

Tags: html, css

I am coding an HTML drumpad program like this, I'm styling it with CSS:

```css
#drumpad-container {
    display: grid;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Drumpad</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='..\CSS\drumpad.css'/>
    <script src='..\JS\drumpad.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='drumpad-container'>
        <div id='drumpadQ'>'Q'</div>
        <div id='drumpadW'>'W'</div>
        <div id='drumpadE'>'E'</div>
        <div id='drumpadA'>'A'</div>
        <div id='drumpadS'>'S'</div>
        <div id='drumpadD'>'D'</div>
        <div id='drumpadZ'>'Z'</div>
        <div id='drumpadX'>'X'</div>
        <div id='drumpadC'>'C'</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My goal is to have the `<div>` tags in a grid, 3 x 3.
The HTML works, but the CSS doesn't!
Someone please help?!

Comment: Why are you assuming the browser knows what you want? You haven't specified anything related to the dimensions of the grid.

Comment: There are online grid generators, simply **google it** and learn from the generated code.

Comment: I have tried specifying grid dimensions, but no result...

Comment: We can assist you if you provide what your drumpard.css file contains. from there we can see where you are

Comment: You have to explicitly define your grid to be 3x3 with grid-template property on your parent div.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to define the columns and rows of #drumpad-container.

See this page for more help with CSS Grid.  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

```
#drumpad-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto; /* or 33% 33% auto; or 25% 50% 25%; etc. */
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
}
```

Comment: Wow, I feel like a total noob!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the grid template. In this case, you only need [`grid-template-columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns).

```css
#drumpad-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Drumpad</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='..\CSS\drumpad.css'/>
    <script src='..\JS\drumpad.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='drumpad-container'>
        <div id='drumpadQ'>'Q'</div>
        <div id='drumpadW'>'W'</div>
        <div id='drumpadE'>'E'</div>
        <div id='drumpadA'>'A'</div>
        <div id='drumpadS'>'S'</div>
        <div id='drumpadD'>'D'</div>
        <div id='drumpadZ'>'Z'</div>
        <div id='drumpadX'>'X'</div>
        <div id='drumpadC'>'C'</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

See [A Complete Guide to Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) for more information.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by set `#drumpad-container{display:grid;grid-template-columns: auto auto auto}`

For more information visit this link [enter link description here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp)

```css
#drumpad-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Drumpad</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='..\CSS\drumpad.css'/>
    <script src='..\JS\drumpad.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='drumpad-container'>
        <div id='drumpadQ'>'Q'</div>
        <div id='drumpadW'>'W'</div>
        <div id='drumpadE'>'E'</div>
        <div id='drumpadA'>'A'</div>
        <div id='drumpadS'>'S'</div>
        <div id='drumpadD'>'D'</div>
        <div id='drumpadZ'>'Z'</div>
        <div id='drumpadX'>'X'</div>
        <div id='drumpadC'>'C'</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```